# DataBind GridView OnKeyUp/Down

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that will display customer information.  I want it to update the results as the user types first and/or last name into the textboxes.  Basically, to databind the gridview to it's datasource with the updated characters from the textboxes as the user types.

CODE EDITED:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Process.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reservations.WebForm3" %>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
        AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>Processing...</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" runat ="server" class="inputLarge" ontextchanged="firstname_TextChanged" />
      <asp:TextBox ID="lastname" runat="server" class="inputLarge" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="457px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustID" HeaderText="Cust ID">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts></Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="firstname" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void firstname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InventoryAppSoapClient inst = new InventoryAppSoapClient();
        DataSet ds = inst.getCustomer(firstname.Text, "none");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();           
    }
```

Everything works except the TextChanged event only first the first time.  If I go back and change the text and tab off, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an event handler for the OnTextChanged event of your text box.

Inside you could force the databind like so

```
Private void firstName_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your datasource and parameters are already defined on the front end so there is no 
//setup required
 existing.DataBind();
}
```

Same goes for your text box lastName

```
Private void lastName_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your datasource and parameters are already defined on the front end so there is no 
//setup required
 existing.DataBind();
}
```

And don't forget to add the methods to the OnTextChange attribute for each textbox in the front end. Like so.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="firstname" OnTextChanged="firstName_OnTextChanged" runat ="server" class="inputLarge"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="lastname" OnTextChanged="lastName_OnTextChanged" runat="server" class="inputLarge" />
```

Also, if you embed this code in an update Panel and use the AJAX control toolkit (free) the grid will update seamlessly. Otherwise it won't be pretty if you use classic asp techniques. The page will keep posting back every time you press a key. It will get annoying.

Comment: I've thought of that, but I want the grid to update as the user types. onTextChanged doesn't fire until the textbox loses focus.  Is there no way to bind in javascript or JQuery using the onKeyUp and onKeyDown events?

Comment: I am trying your suggestion but the gridview doesn't respond to the existing.DataBind() call in the firstname_OnTextChanged() event.  I've tested the query when configuring the datasource so I know that it should return a result.  Is it maybe struggling because the gridview is initially empty?

Comment: If you're using an update panel I need to see the HTML markup completely as you may have to declare an asynchronous trigger.

Comment: It is.  I've gotten it to where everything works except the ontextchanged event only fires the first time.  If I go back to the textbox, change the text and tab off a 2nd time, nothing happens.  I'll update my code

Comment: Can you added your @page directives as well? Are you using the ajax control toolkit?

Comment: @page directives added.  Yes I am using the ajax toolkit.

Comment: After restarting visual studio this morning everything seems to be working.  Just one of those crazy quirks I suppose. Still haven't had my original question answered though.  onKeyUp or onKeyDown?